# Why this validation code does not work as expected?

Tags: php, arrays, forms, validation

I have a form and the action of the for m is same page.
I am trying to :

1. Show a thanks message upon the successful form submission
2. Show error messages next to the field where the error is detected
3. All the above must be shown in the same page.

My code is :

```
<?php
    $errors = array();
    if (isset($_POST["Ask_the_Question"])) {
        $guest_name = $_POST["guest_name"];
        $title = $_POST["faq_title"];
        $description = $_POST["faq_desc"];
        $title = $_POST["faq_title"];

        /* validation */
        if (empty($guest_name)) {
            $errors['guest_name'] = "Please type your name!";
        }   

        if(!empty($errors)){ echo '<h1 style="color: #ff0000;">Errors!</h1><h6 style="color: #ff0000;">Please check the fields which have errors below. Error hints are in Red.</h6>';}

        if(empty($errors)){     
            echo 'Thanks, We have received your feed back';
        }
    }

    else {
?>
            <form action="index.php" method="post" class="booking_reference">
                <input type="text" name="guest_name" placeholder="Your Name" value="<?PHP if(!empty($errors)) { echo $guest_name;} ?>" />
                <?php if(isset($errors['guest_name'])) { echo '<span style="color: red">'.$errors['guest_name'].'</span>'; } ?>
                <input type="email" name="guest_email" placeholder="Your email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$" required />
                <input type="text" name="faq_title" placeholder="FAQ Title"/>
                <input type="text" name="faq_desc" placeholder="FAQ Description"/>
                <input type="submit" name="Ask_the_Question" value="Ask the Question" />
            </form>
<?php
        }
?>
```

I've limited the validation and showing only for first part in this QUESTION.

When I submit this form If there is NO any errors the I am getting the message **Thanks, We have received your feed back**
That's fine and works as expected.

When an error exists / the field **Guest name** is empty I am getting the message during the form submission **Errors!
Please check the fields which have errors below. Error hints are in Red.**
That's also fine.

But my **form is just disappear** when I get the above message. Why?
Also I want show that **Please type your name!** next to the field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try bellow code. I have removed else part and set flag with true/false to check from is valid or not.

```
<?php
    $errors = array();
    if (isset($_POST["Ask_the_Question"])) {
        $guest_name = $_POST["guest_name"];
        $title = $_POST["faq_title"];
        $description = $_POST["faq_desc"];
        $title = $_POST["faq_title"];

        /* validation */
        $chkValidate = "true";
        if (empty($guest_name)) {
            $errors['guest_name'] = "Please type your name!";
            $chkValidate = "false";
        }   

        if(!empty($errors)){ echo '<h1 style="color: #ff0000;">Errors!</h1><h6 style="color: #ff0000;">Please check the fields which have errors below. Error hints are in Red.</h6>';
            $chkValidate = "false";
        }

        if($chkValidate == "true"){     
            echo 'Thanks, We have received your feed back';
        }
    }
    ?>
            <form action="index.php" method="post" class="booking_reference">
                <input type="text" name="guest_name" placeholder="Your Name" value="<?php if(!empty($errors) && $chkValidate != "false") { echo $guest_name;} ?>" />
                <?php if(isset($errors['guest_name'])) { echo '<span style="color: red">'.$errors['guest_name'].'</span>'; } ?>
                <input type="email" name="guest_email" placeholder="Your email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$" required  />
                <input type="text" name="faq_title" placeholder="FAQ Title"/>
                <input type="text" name="faq_desc" placeholder="FAQ Description"/>
                <input type="submit" name="Ask_the_Question" value="Ask the Question" />
            </form>
<?php

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `else` condition cause actually your form will not be display if `$_POST["Ask_the_Question"]` is set

```
<?php
    $errors = array();
    if (isset($_POST["Ask_the_Question"])) {
        $guest_name = $_POST["guest_name"];
        $title = $_POST["faq_title"];
        $description = $_POST["faq_desc"];
        $title = $_POST["faq_title"];

        /* validation */
        if (empty($guest_name)) {
            $errors['guest_name'] = "Please type your name!";
        }   

        if(!empty($errors)){ echo '<h1 style="color: #ff0000;">Errors!</h1><h6 style="color: #ff0000;">Please check the fields which have errors below. Error hints are in Red.</h6>';}

        if(empty($errors)){     
            echo 'Thanks, We have received your feed back';
        }
    }
            <form action="index.php" method="post" class="booking_reference">
                <input type="text" name="guest_name" placeholder="Your Name" value="<?PHP if(!empty($errors)) { echo $guest_name;} ?>" />
                <?php if(isset($errors['guest_name'])) { echo '<span style="color: red">'.$errors['guest_name'].'</span>'; } ?>
                <input type="email" name="guest_email" placeholder="Your email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$" required />
                <input type="text" name="faq_title" placeholder="FAQ Title"/>
                <input type="text" name="faq_desc" placeholder="FAQ Description"/>
                <input type="submit" name="Ask_the_Question" value="Ask the Question" />
            </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why is here:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["Ask_the_Question"])) {
        $guest_name = $_POST["guest_name"];
        $title = $_POST["faq_title"];
        $description = $_POST["faq_desc"];
        $title = $_POST["faq_title"];

        /* validation */
        if (empty($guest_name)) {
            $errors['guest_name'] = "Please type your name!";
        }   

        if(!empty($errors)){ echo '<h1 style="color: #ff0000;">Errors!</h1><h6 style="color: #ff0000;">Please check the fields which have errors below. Error hints are in Red.</h6>';}

        if(empty($errors)){     
            echo 'Thanks, We have received your feed back';
        }
    } else {
      // your form code will never be called if $_POST['Ask_the_Question'] is set
```

TO do what you want to achieve you probably want to do something like this instead:

```
<?php
    $errors = array();
    if (isset($_POST["Ask_the_Question"])) {
        $guest_name = $_POST["guest_name"];
        $title = $_POST["faq_title"];
        $description = $_POST["faq_desc"];
        $title = $_POST["faq_title"];

        /* validation */
        if (empty($guest_name)) {
            $errors['guest_name'] = "Please type your name!";
        }   

        if(!empty($errors)){ echo '<h1 style="color: #ff0000;">Errors!</h1><h6 style="color: #ff0000;">Please check the fields which have errors below. Error hints are in Red.</h6>';}
     }

     if(empty($errors)){     
          echo 'Thanks, We have received your feed back';
      } else { ?>
            <form action="index.php" method="post" class="booking_reference">
                <input type="text" name="guest_name" placeholder="Your Name" value="<?PHP if(!empty($errors)) { echo $guest_name;} ?>" />
                <?php if(isset($errors['guest_name'])) { echo '<span style="color: red">'.$errors['guest_name'].'</span>'; } ?>
                <input type="email" name="guest_email" placeholder="Your email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$" required />
                <input type="text" name="faq_title" placeholder="FAQ Title"/>
                <input type="text" name="faq_desc" placeholder="FAQ Description"/>
                <input type="submit" name="Ask_the_Question" value="Ask the Question" />
            </form>
           <?php

        }
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Other answers are fine, but just to clarify what happens.

> But my form is just disappear when I get the above message. Why?

Your form disappear because if you pass the first *if* you can't get to your *else*.

```
if (isset($_POST["Ask_the_Question"])) {
    ...
} else {
    xxx;
}
```

That means if you want to see your form you have to put it somewhere it can be shown like [elseif](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php) (with more restrictions), or ifs inner or outer.

```
if (isset($_POST["Ask_the_Question"]) && empty($errors)) {
    ...
} elseif (isset($_POST["Ask_the_Question"]) && !empty($errors)) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

> Also I want show that Please type your name! next to the field.

To show all errors you could use eg. foreach anywhere you want to show them.

```
foreach ($errors as &$error) {
    echo "Error: $error<br />\n";
}
```

Btw be careful with the [empty(); function](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=cs&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=cs&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fblog.zdenekvecera.cz%2Fitem%2Fvite-jak-se-chova-zakerna-php-funkce-empty&edit-text=&act=url).